# Sending text area values as request to spring is always null

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have two textarea boxes like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment">Numbers:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="numbers" placeholder="Numbers in one per line format"></textarea>
    <br>
    <label for="comment">Message:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" ng-model="message" ng-trim="true" placeholder="Enter your message here"></textarea>
</div>
```

I am sending the request from angular:

```
$scope.sendSMS = function () {
    var formData = {
        numbers: $scope.numbers,
        message: $scope.message
    };

    Auth.sendSMS(formData, successAuth, function () {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(formData)); //prints both values
        $rootScope.error = 'Message not sent';
        console.log($rootScope.error);
    });
};
```

Auth service (http post):

```
return{
    sendSMS: function(data, success, error){
        $http.post('mvc-dispatcher/sendSMS', data).success(success).error(error);
    }
}
```

While on front-end I am able to print both the values before sending, however on server-side the text area for message is always taking it is null and text-area for number is printing correctly:

```
Numbers: 123456789
message: null
```

I am not sure what went wrong. There is no error on server-side nor frontend

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class smsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendSMS", consumes = "application/json", headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void sendMessage(@RequestBody MessageBean msgBean) {

        String numbers = msgBean.getNumbers();
        System.out.println("Numbers: " + numbers);
        String message = msgBean.getMessages();
        System.out.println("message: " + message);
    }
}
```

Dispatcher-servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.rest.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Jars used:

```
jackson-annotations-2.7.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.7.3.jar
jackson-core-2.7.3.jar
Spring Framework release 4.2.2
```

Message Bean:

```
public class MessageBean {

    private String numbers;
    private String messages;

    public String getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public void setNumbers(String numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public String getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(String messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a wrong parameter name, try this;)

```
var formData = {
    numbers: $scope.numbers,
    message: $scope.message
};
```

**Edited:**
Now we are clear, you declared a field `messages` in `MessageBean`, but you tried to give it a parameter named `message`, `message` will not be matched to `messages` when Spring do convertering things, so you should try this;)

```
var formData = {
    numbers: $scope.numbers,
    messages: $scope.message
};
```

Comment: That was a typo. I have already tried with correct parameter name and still the same null value for message

Comment: `numbers` is also a `textarea`, and in your post, server seems to get the value of it. That's weird... Could you show code snippet of your serve-side?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @Satyadev Could you post `MessageBean` as well? I've noticed that `message`'s getter method is `getMessages`, one more character `s` at last.

Comment: Updated with message bean

Comment: The getMessages looks right or else IDE would have show compile time error

Comment: Yeah, `getMessages` is definitely right, you can try my **edited** code in frondend.

Comment: whoaa...good catch..coming from servlet where we use `request.parameter('message')` where we map it based on name parameter provided inside html tag where in for angular `messages` that stores scope variable becomes name parameter. Actually I was thinking `ng-model=message` as name paramater